# Netbeans C++ IDE on Windows does not recognize shared object as executable on remote Ubuntu machine for C++ remote debugging purposes

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans

My build server is an Ubuntu 18.04 distro, and the GCC is whatever comes stock with Ubuntu.  I can build and run my C++ application via the command line no problem, including with dbg.  Here is the file info:

ken@ken-PowerEdge-R420:/git-repos/septemmud/septemserver/Debug$ file septemserver
septemserver: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9df5db0ee3dfc296ef8e6e83c51b8ca195566ff2, with debug_info, not stripped
ken@ken-PowerEdge-R420:/git-repos/septemmud/septemserver/Debug$

However, the latest release of netbeans running on my windows PC does not recognize my septemserver as an executable for remote debugging.  This makes no sense to me.  I found an older post that suggested the --no-pie option on compile.. which I have.  Still no luck and cannot find anyone else with this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if the toolchain on your windows machine is set to understand PE formats only , such is the case with some builds of mingw, you wont be able to debug non PE formats. What you really should be doing is set your netbeans on windows to log into your ubuntu and start a remote debugging session with it's gdb, and then have your gdb connect to it, then you can debug your code remotely. That's what I did when cross compiling with QtCreator and the linaro toolchain (arm embedded). good luck!

Comment: The fix turned out to be having the -no-pie option in the linker arguments, not the preprocessor.  I'm a nub.

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem figured out.